# Calculate time between two actions within session

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a following table structure

```
id | sessionId | event | created_on
---|-----------|-------|--------------------
 1 | 1         | view  | 2016-01-01 12:24:01
 2 | 1         | buy   | 2016-01-01 12:25:05
 3 | 2         | view  | 2016-01-01 12:25:09
 4 | 1         | view  | 2016-01-01 12:27:10
......
```

I'm trying to get time between two events, in this particular case I want to know how much time have passed between FIRST view and FIRST buy event within a session.

How do I apply WHERE for data within GROUP BY? Basically I want to group by sesssionID and get only sessions which include both view and buy actions and I want to get time between FIRST view and FIRST buy event for a single session.

How do I achieve required result?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution could be:
Take the minimum created_at per sessionID  where event is view and join it with the minimum created at per sessionID  where event is buy. Use inner join to have only records with both...

> select A.sessionID,A.firstView,B.firstBuy, datedif(*depend on rdbms*) from
>
> (select sessionID,min(created_on) as firstView  from tblName  where event ='view' group by sessionID ) A
>
> Inner join
>
> (select sessionID,min(created_on) as firstBuy from tblName where event ='buy' group by sessionID ) B
>
> On A.sessionID = B.sessionID

Comment: ah, indeed! I could just join it. Thank you for the idea.

Answer (score 3):

Rather common sql syntax which hopefully google-bigquery supports

```
select sessionId, 
  min(case event when 'view' then created_on end) as firstView,
  min(case event when 'buy' then created_on end) as firstBuy
from t
where event in ('view', 'buy')
group by sessionId
having max(event) != min(event)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to avoid extra JOINs - try below

```
SELECT 
  sessionId, 
  TIMESTAMP_TO_SEC(firstBuy) - TIMESTAMP_TO_SEC(firstView) AS sec_to_buy
FROM (
  SELECT sessionId, 
    MIN(CASE WHEN event = 'view' THEN created_on END) AS firstView,
    MIN(CASE WHEN event = 'buy' THEN created_on END) AS firstBuy
  FROM (
    SELECT * FROM 
      (SELECT 1 AS sessionId, 'view' AS event, TIMESTAMP('2016-01-01 12:24:01') AS created_on),
      (SELECT 1 AS sessionId, 'buy' AS event,  TIMESTAMP('2016-01-01 12:25:05') AS created_on),
      (SELECT 2 AS sessionId, 'view' AS event, TIMESTAMP('2016-01-01 12:25:09') AS created_on),
      (SELECT 1 AS sessionId, 'view' AS event, TIMESTAMP('2016-01-01 12:27:10') AS created_on),
  )
  GROUP BY sessionId
  HAVING firstView <= firstBuy
)
```